# Collapse of a subspace - Cofibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $i:A \rightarrow X$ be a (closed ) cofibration (i.e a cofibration in the Strøm Model structure). For a subspace $B \subset A \subset X$, when is it true that $A/B \rightarrow X / B$ is a cofibration?

Comment: What do you mean with Strøm model structure?

Comment: @Stefan H : The modrl structure on Top where fibrations are Hurewicz fibrations and weak equivalences homotopy equivalences.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$
The diagram
$$\small{\begin{CD}
A @>i>> X \\
@VVV  @VVV\\
A/B @>j>> X/B
\end{CD}}$$
is a pushout. It is a general fact in category theory that if a map in a diagram $\bullet\leftarrow\bullet\to\bullet$ has the LLP (left lifting property) w.r.t. a class of maps, then the parallel map in the induced pushout diagram has the LLP for this class, as well. Since the cofibrations are precisely the maps with the LLP with respect to the class of acyclic fibrations, $i$ being a cofibration implies that $j$ is cofibration.